# Ιs Pycelle really a wizened old man?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

Ι just saw [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6m4V4D_ba8) deleted scene from Game of Thrones, where Pycelle stands up straight and talks normally.

Is this in the books? Or was this to be a plot twist in the show?

Also, does anyone have any ideas as to why wouldn't they show this?

Comment: I seem to recall there being another scene (in the TV-show) where we see Pycelle do some kind of agile jump, which implies this same thing, that he is only acting old. I do not recall any such thing being in the books. On the contrary, in the books he is 84 years old. He was a teenager during the reign of [King Maekar I](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maekar_I) (Maester Aemon's father, Rhaegar's great-great grandfather). About the same age as Walder Frey and Jon Arryn. The man we see in this scene looks much younger than that, so I would say this is just in the TV-show.

Comment: @TLP i remember no such scene, can u provide the episode?

Comment: [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHJTYqLtRms) is the exact scene I am talking about, where Pycelle starts out talking about Kings with the prostitute Ros and pretending to be a doddering old man, but when she leaves, he drops the act. Not sure which episode or season its from.

Comment: Link is dead. Could you update and provide a description of the scene. I was thinking of answer but then realized you might actually be referring that the scene, but I have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That particular scene is not in the books, but it is implied multiple times that Pycelle is only *acting* like a harmless, decrepit old man. When Tyrion's men arrest Pycelle in [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHJTYqLtRms) for leaking information to Queen Cersei he is found in bed with a naked girl, confirming that he is quite spry for a man of his advanced years. The Grand Maester dabbles heavily in politics and backstabbing, mostly to aid House Lannister, and to direct attention away from himself he acts like a doddering old fool.

Comment: +1. the show (as it often does) take's the book's implications a bit further -- he basically does calisthenics on TV -- but the underlying meaning is still the same.

Comment: In the books Pycelle also returns from spending his time at Tyrion's leisure in the Black Cells a substantial shadow of his former self.